# When should I ask questions on here (meta math SE) and when should I ask on über meta?

Tags: support, allowed-questions, meta

It is my understanding if my question is about math.SE and can't be generalized to other SEs, here is better. If my question is about site functionality then über meta is better. Is this understanding correct?

If so how should we handle questions about site functionality that are posted on here instead of über meta?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is basically correct but a slight overstatement. It is true that this site is for questions specific to math.se (and those would, in general, not be on-topic for meta.se), yet I would not say that questions about site functionality are always better on meta.se.

Meta.se is for questions and discussions relevant to the entire network or at least to more than one site. A question is better asked there if input from or information of  other communities (or SE) is relevant.

Questions that just also apply to other sites can go either here or there. Usually, standard support questions are better handled on a per site meta, and there is no point in directing those towards meta.se. Indeed, I would be against doing this.

More broadly, I do not think we should push users towards using meta.se. In the rare case that a question comes up here where it seems important it is on meta.se, we can point it out, but really it is rare.

Comment: I like this answer. I very rarely visit Meta for general browsing, and learn about site mechanics (how flags are handled, moderation tools, etc) primarily from browsing our meta, following links to Meta as necessary. I would learn very little if these types of questions were not on our meta as well (although this is of course a selfish perspective, I'm sure I'm not alone).

Comment: Indeed this is a main reason why I think it would not be good to direct too much towards the general meta.